# Sockets, server disconnection and connection reset error in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, sockets, error-handling, server, disconnect

I have created a Python server that communicates with an Android client using sockets. Now I'm trying to implement error handling in case of server disconnection.

Initially, the client is connected to the socket, but after a forced server interruption occurs, I want the client to automatically try to reconnect to the server and wait until it becomes available again.

When the server is restarted, the reconnection happens successfully. However, when the `while (running)` loop is restarted, a `ConnectionResetException` is thrown at the line `bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(buffer)`.

I'm trying to understand how to handle this exception, and I'm not sure if it depends solely on the client side. Any clues?

```
    private inner class Receiver(private val dataInputStream: DataInputStream) : Thread() {
    val dataReceivedListeners = mutableListOf<(ByteArray) -> Unit>()
    private var running = true

    override fun run() {
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var bytesRead: Int
        val dataBuilder = StringBuilder()

        while (running) {
            try {
                bytesRead = dataInputStream.read(buffer)
                if (bytesRead <= 0) {
                    break
                }
                # DATA HANDLING ...
            }
            catch (e: SocketException){
                reconnected = false
                var tries = 0
                while (tries<5){
                    if (!reconnected){
                        reconnect()
                        tries +=1
                        Thread.sleep(1000)
                    }
                    else {
                        break
                    }
                }
                if (tries >= 5 && !reconnected) {
                    Log.d("Reconnection failed", "All reconnection attempts failed")
                    break
                }
            }

        }
    }
}

var reconnected = true


private fun reconnect() {
    // Close the current connection
    try {
        client?.close()
        client = null
        sender = null
        receiver = null

        client = Socket()
        val address = InetSocketAddress("192.168.***.***", 8888)
        client!!.connect(address, 20000)

        // Update the sender and receiver with new streams
        val outputStream = client?.getOutputStream()
        val inputStream = client?.getInputStream()
        sender = Sender(DataOutputStream(outputStream))
        receiver = Receiver(DataInputStream(inputStream))

        receiver?.dataReceivedListeners?.add { data ->
            dataReceivedListeners.forEach { listener ->
                listener(data)
            }
        }
        receiver?.start()

        reconnected = true
        Log.d("Reconnection", "Reconnection happened")
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        reconnected = false
        Log.d("Reconnection failed", "Reconnection has failed")
    }
}
```

}

Comment: There are some basic syntax errors in this code that prevent it from running (e.g., there is an `else` in `handle_client` that is not part of the preceding `if` statement). You should fix these first, and consider if there is a way to reduce the amount of code in your question while still demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @larsks Ok, I've improved the code a little bit, I hope that now is clearer.